# Why are all my smartphone photos coming out near-white?

Tags: exposure, troubleshooting, camera-settings, nokia

I have been using a Nokia 808 PureView for the last 22 months. Until recently, it was working fine but a few weeks ago, the headset port was not working, so I took it to the nearest store and had it changed. Since then,  when I take photos in any mode (automatic, scene or creative), the photos come out almost entirely white, even when the flash is off and at low ISO. (Doing a factory reset on the phone has had no effect).

Here is a photo I took recently; the shooting parameters were

- Mode: automatic
- Exposure time: 1/321 s
- ISO: 50
- White balance: automatic
- Resolution: 3072 * 1728

The picture was taken around 8 am when there was only a little sunlight.

[image]

What could be the problem here?

Comment: You say it was after changing headphones that this happened?  Could you have damaged the socket, allowing light leakage into the body of the camera?  Easy test - try placing some black elecrical or gaffer (slightly stickier) tape over the headphone socket, try taking another photo. Does this phenomenon still happen?!

Comment: Yes...I tried the method you told me, but, it didn't work. @Mike

Comment: For avoidance of doubt: could you clarify what you mean by "changed a headset port"? Was this just plugging / unplugging headphones, or did you actually open the camera up to make some more significant changes? Secondly, have you tried doing a factory reset on the phone?

Comment: Factory reset didn't produce nedded results. I have updated the question. @Philip Kendall

Comment: Assuming it was someone at the store that physically changed the headset port, take it back to the store and say "you broke it. You fix it, or give me a working phone".

Comment: My question is why photos taken during daytime contains more white noise (with or without flash) than the pics taken during night??? If it had to do something with a malfunctioned camera, I should have faced this problem the whole time.. @Philip Kendall

Comment: Because the camera is broken and is *massively* overexposing.

Comment: Can that be fixed?? @Philip Kendall

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, this looks very much like whoever changed your headset port has also managed to damage the camera module in some way so that it is massively overexposing. This is very unlikely to be fixable by an amateur - I'd suggest taking it back to the store that changed the headset port and getting them to either fix it or give you a replacement phone, because it's clear that they didn't take sufficient care when changing the headset port.

What would be very useful at this stage is if you have some photos taken with the camera from just before you took the phone in to have the headset port repaired, so that you can show that it was the work done in the store which caused the damage.